# Defining a task -- or macro -- in ant-script

Tags: ant

We have a large `build.xml` file with some tasks repeated verbatim in multiple targets -- such as a long-winded `<echo>`, which updates the log-file(s) with contents of an object:

```xml
<echo file="foo.log" message="${run.name} completed with status ${run.status}. Errors: ${run.errors}, warnings: ${run.warnings}, processed ${run.processed}"/>
```

Can this be turned into something like `<logrun file="file.log" run=${run}"/>` -- *in the XML*? That is, without us writing [Java-code to implement the new `logrun`-task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, using the Ant [`<macrodef>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html) task.

Something like this:

```
<macrodef name="logrun">
   <attribute name="file"/>
   <attribute name="name"/>
   <attribute name="status"/>
   <attribute name="errors"/>
   <attribute name="warnings"/>
   <attribute name="processed"/>
  <sequential>
    <echo file="@{file}"
          message="@{name} completed with status @{status}. Errors: @{errors}, warnings: @{warnings}, processed @{processed}${line.separator}"/>
  </sequential>
</macrodef>

<logrun file="foo.log" name="foo.name" status="foo.status" errors="foo.errors" warnings="foo.warnings" processed="foo.processed" />
```

Notice the way named macro parameters are referenced in the "body" of the macro using `@`-prefix.  I added a `${line.separator}` at the end of the message parameter, so that the line written to the file is terminated.  You might want to use `append="true"` in the echo task, in order that the file is not completely overwritten each time the macro is called.

A macro might cater for all your attribute edge cases, depends how complex they are.

Comment: I attempted to pass just the `${run}` -- and log the fields like `@{run.status}` -- but these were never expanded, I got the literal strings like "`@{run.status}` in the log. Any idea, why?

Comment: @ should only be used inside the macro definition, not when calling the macro.  To pass in a property value, reference it in the usual way with a dollar prefix: `${run.status},` and so on.

Comment: So, one cannot pass an "object" -- like `${run}` -- and have all its fields available in the macro? The fields must instead be spelled out -- as _strings_ -- individually?

Comment: I don't think ant properties are realy objects. you can use properties in your macro and pass the name of the property as a macro parameter
`
<macrodef name="objrun">
   <attribute name="obj"/>
  <sequential>
    <echo message="${@{obj}.name} completed with status ${@{obj}.status}. Errors: ${@{obj}.errors}, warnings: ${@{obj}.warnings}, processed ${@{obj}.processed}${line.separator}"/>
  </sequential>
</macrodef>

<property name="first.name" value="first run" />
<property name="first.status" value="first succes" />

<objrun obj="first" />
`